# Server 2012R2 cannot ping default gateway

Tags: vmware-player, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using VMPlayer 12 to host Server 2012R2. Several of them. (Learning Server Administration). I have created the DC serverr and joined another server to the DC. At one time recently the servers could all ping the default gateway; I *believe* (because I didn't document it) the VMPlayer Network adapter setting was VMNet1 (host-only). Here is the results of IPConfig/all:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Server2012DC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : bigfoot.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : bigfoot.com

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network            Connection
  Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-58-91-55
  DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
  Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
  Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6c00:7258:6a75:c584%12(Preferred) 
  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.172(Preferred) 
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
  DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301993001
  DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1B-D9-E1-6A-00-0C-29-58-91-55
  DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                   127.0.0.1
  NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

  Tunnel adapter isatap.{06716BD5-EC62-45CB-87AD-1EEF34DAFA57}:

  Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
  Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
  Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
  Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
  DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
  Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

But now this server cannot ping the default gateway and the other servers cannot ping it. Any help like where to look to resolve this is greatly appreciated.

VMPlayer has several network adapter settings: Bridged, VMnet0 - VMNet19. The documentation, as much as I can find, seems to suggest Bridged works if you want the VMs to connect to the host adapter, which I do. I know that in the recent past this work just fine and now not. I just need some advice on where to look. I can't figure out how to diagnose it more deeply.

I changed the Network Adatper NAT; created a new VM. I started another VM also with the Adapter set to NAT. The new VM can ping the other one but not visa versa. TO me they seem identical in most respects.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your IPcofing dump would indicate a problem pinging the gateway.

Note: This computer has itself configured as the only DNS server. I assume this screen shot was from a DC and is thus likely a DNS server, so that's fine for labs but unless you have the DNS server configured properly external queries are going to be problematic. You could always cheat and add google as a secondary DNS server if you don't want to bother configuring forwarders.

Make sure all the VMS are connected to the same virtual switch and are on the same network. If the gateway is the host, go to the host's network settings and make sure you have the appropriate static IP address set for the virtual network adapter.

If the DC is connected to multiple virtual switches you can use

```
ping -S
```

to specify a specific NIC to use by IP address (Be careful the switch is case sensitive, -s is a different parameter. Check ping /? if you need clarification).

Check your routing table to make sure you have the appropriate gateway configured there as well. That SHOULDN'T be a problem, but if you've been messing with network settings, sometimes things happen in labs.

What is your gateway, the host? What OS is the gateway running? If it's a Windows client OS check your network profile and/or firewall rules.